# Showing date on main.gsp

Tags: layout, grails

I want to show date on main.gsp. Do I just call g:formatDate? Because I did that but date is not rendered:

```
<span id='loginLink'  style='position: absolute; right: 20px; top: 20px;'>
          <sec:ifLoggedIn>
              You are logged in as:<sec:username/> (<g:link controller='logout'>Logout</g:link>)
          </sec:ifLoggedIn>
          <sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
             <g:link controller='login'>Login</g:link>
          </sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
    </span>
    <span style='position: absolute; right: 20px; top: 40px;'>
        Date:<g:formatDate format="yyyy-MM-dd" date="${date}"/>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that the 'main' controller action returns the 'date' variable containing the actual date? For example:

```
def main =  {
    [date: new Date()]
}
```

Another solution would be to instanciate the Date class directly in your gsp code.

```
<g:formatDate format="yyyy-MM-dd" date="${new Date()}"/>
```

Comment: This worked. But I don't why it didn't worked my way because as I understood the implementation of g:formatDate it should have worked:  `def date
        if (attrs.containsKey('date')) {
            date = attrs.date
            if (date == null) return
        }
        else {
            date = new Date()
        }`

Comment: Do not give the date param to the tag if you want that else clause to get invoked.